# Which language for cover letter, CV and interview

Tags: interviewing, resume, cover-letter

I am an italian guy who wants to send my cv to a danish company. This company is set in Milan and I think that italian is the only language they'll speak in the workplace, but their site, facebook page and the application itself are written in english language.

My english is far away to be perfect (as you can read ;) ), so my question is: should I write my cover letter, portfolio, cv and go on in english, although I think the workplace and the interviewer will be italian?

Comment: @Lilienthal: Yes, that's quite the same situation, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would always be a safe bet to write them in English.

> My english is far away to be perfect

You can always hire someone to proofread and correct your resume on Fiverr.com, shouldn't take more than six bucks.  I do it for proof-reading my research papers, and they do a good job at that.

So, send them in English to be on the safe side. You don't want to get embarrassed by sending them the documents in a language they don't understand, and definitely don't send them before getting them proofread properly.

Comment: Luckly my girlfriend has a CAE C1 level and I can trust her in proofreading. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Ahh shoot, you're one lucky fellow. Mine isn't. Even though she swears on her English proficiency, I don't risk my research on that  :D

Comment: @Dawny33 Trust me, your English is pretty darn good...